# Number of ways to represent $n^{12}$ as a sum of three positive cubes

Tags: number-theory

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $N = n^{12}$. Show that there are at least $9^{-1/3}\cdot N^{1/12}$ ways to express $N$ as the sum of three *positive* cubes.
>
> As a hint the identity $$(9m^4)^3+(3mn^3-9m^4)^3+(n^4-9m^3n)^3 = n^{12}$$
> is mentioned.

I have no idea how to do that. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: For how many choices of $m$ are all the three numbers positive?

Comment: He gave you the identity $a(m,n)^3 + b(m,n)^3 + c(m,n)^3 = n^{12}$. You can consider how many $m$'s there are such that $a,b,c > 0$ for a fixed $|n|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a consequence of the identity mentioned, all we need to show is that there are at least $9^{-1/3}n$ choices of $m\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ for which each of the terms $9m^4,3mn^3-9m^4,n^4-9m^3n$ are positive.  Of course $9m^4$ is trivially positive so long as $m\neq 0$, and the other conditions give us
$$n^3>3m^3,\quad n^3>9m^3.$$
Of course the first inequality is already satisfied so long as the second is satisfied, but the second inequality is just $m<9^{-1/3}n$. Now, since $9^{-1/3}$ is irrational and hence $9^{-1/3}n$ is surely not integral, then the sequence of values $m=1,2,\dots,\lfloor 9^{-1/3}n\rfloor$ works. This doesn't quite solve the problem, but we only need one more value of $m$. I'll leave that to you.